# How to export a printer with its drivers and deploy it on other machine on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printer

I tried below commands got from this [link](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/transfer-file-using-usb-69830.html).

For exporting printer:
printui.exe /Ss /n "KONICA MINOLTA Universal PCL" /a "konica_printer.dat"

Only 55KB dat file generated whereas the setup file is 7 MB.

For importing:
printui /Sr /n "KONICA MINOLTA Universal PCL" /a "C:\Users\uday\Desktop\konica_printer.dat"

But I am getting below error while importing.

[image: Error while importing]

This [approach](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/HowToMigrateWindowsPrintQueues#migrating-or-backing-up-your-windows-print-server) seems to work but it is migrating all the printers,not a specific one and no command line option to import back

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://winscripting.wordpress.com/2021/05/03/export-and-import-printers/)

This shows how to export and import using command line.